# Validation of converted JSON against XML or XSD

Tags: json, xml, xsd, apache-nifi

I have an XML and XSD file. I am using Apache NiFi to convert XML to JSON. However, it is nested in many levels and hence I want to  validate if the conversion is fine. I  want to validate the same using XSD in Apache NiFi.
I will not be able to share the company sensitive information.
Is there any processor or script that I can use? there is an option of writing Python script in a processor called ExecuteScript.

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your question.

1. Can JSON be validated via XSD?
2. Does nifi have a processor that validates JSON via XSD?

The first part already is answered here:
[Validate JSON against XML Schema (XSD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152972/validate-json-against-xml-schema-xsd)

Now for the second part, depending on the solution you end up going with, neither one is implemented in a nifi processor, and attempting to use the ExecuteScript will not work for you because these require use of imported non-native modules.  Instead you would need to create your own custom processor with java and import that into nifi which would solve your problem.  This is all a bit labor intensive.

Alternatively, you could try a reverse conversion back to XML into an attribute and then validate that attribute content against the original XSD.  This is a method I use a lot when writing unit tests.  I haven't personally tried this in nifi, but it sounds like it would be possible and would likely be the least complicated solution.

Comment: See example of converting JSON to DOM for XML schema validation here:  https://github.com/coderextreme/x3dschema (Validate.java is main script).  Sorry, not nifi. I just found out about nifi.